# Excel VBA: unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, but I get error: "unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class"

can anyone help me?

```
Sub ASub()
    'This part is for the Fully Dynamic and Dependent Combobox Client ID and Account Nr.
    'Client ID Part
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clients")
Dim i As Integer

Me.cbox_clientID.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
        Me.cbox_clientID.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no matching in that code.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what your goal is and where the `match` will come into play. What is the issue you are having on your end?

Comment: Just posted the full code. I have two combobox if I select the clintID in the account combobox will show the related account. 
But if I select a client in the clintID and start deleting them with backspace taste I got the error in the topic line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed as following works for my case.

```
'Match Error
On Error Resume Next
```

Answer (score 0):

use "WorksheetFunction.CounA" but "Application.CountA". use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like did not post the full code. I have a list with account nr. If I select one an then I start deleting account nr code bring me the above error msg. as there is no match with the reaming account nr.

```
'Order Input Date Format Order Date
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

'This part is for the Fully Dynamic and Dependent Combobox Client ID and Account Nr.
'Client ID Part

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clients")
Dim i As Integer

Me.cbox_clientID.Clear

For i = 2 To Application.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
    Me.cbox_clientID.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value
Next i

End Sub

'This part is for the Fully Dynamic and Dependent Combobox Client ID and Account Nr.
'Account Part
Private Sub cbox_clientID_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Clients")

Dim i, n As Integer
Me.cbox_account.Clear

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.cbox_clientID.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)

For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
    Me.cbox_account.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value

Next i

Me.cbox_account.ListRows = 20

End Sub
```